# Link up methods to subdomains using CakePHP router

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm looking to make certain urls in my Cake app become subdomain based.

So for example make: `domain.com/posts/index.json` become `api.domain.com/posts`

I've tried:

```
$subdomain = substr(env("HTTP_HOST"), 0, strpos(env("HTTP_HOST"), ".")); 

if ($subdomain == 'api') {
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index')); 
}
```

But it just brings up a 404. Note I've turned off wildcard subdomains so that random subdomains don't still load up the main site (is it possible to allow certain ones? So for example allow api.domain.com but error out on fake.domain.com)

Also how do I handle the JSON extension as part of the router array?

Answer (score 0):

Cake as of 2.x does not have anything to support sub-domains. There has been talks / works on this but not sure when it will be available.

Till it is you will need to live with normal urls or lots of hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below in your routes.php
Also ensure you have the subdomain already accessible.

```
$subdomain = substr( env("HTTP_HOST"), 0, strpos(env("HTTP_HOST"), ".") );
if( strlen($subdomain) > 0 && $subdomain == "api" ) {
    Router::connect('/:action/*', array('controller' => 'posts'));
}
```